# What is the inspiration behind Megamind's mispronunciations?

Tags: megamind

In [Megamind](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1001526/), the eponymous character mispronounces several words, seemingly on purpose (which is actually a bit of a plot element). Examples are "Metrocity", "Spee-ider", "shool". Usually pronouncing words as they are written or putting emphasis on the wrong syllable. Is that in reference to a particular villain who mispronounced words like that?

Comment: My rationale is that since Hal/Titan/Tighten's "father" figure was a clear nod to Marlon Brando's Jor-El, there could be other imitation/homage elements in the movie. The mispronunciation struck me as a likely candidate.

Comment: Honestly, I felt like they were referencing me and my inability to correctly pronounce any word in the English language. That's my story at least.

Comment: One more example: exit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like it's not inspired by any particular villain.

> Tom: I didn’t hear the British in it but we had a French designer on the film and the city’s name is Metrocity and he pronounces it Me-trah-ci-ty. **Will ran with that and he took the idea that this guy wasn’t really formally educated and would mispronounce words.** Will took that kind of handle and ran with it which is very funny in the movie if you’ve seen it.
>    -- [Megamind Interview, Will Ferrell, Tina Fey, David Cross & Director Tom McGrath](http://www.moviesonline.ca/2010/10/megamind-interview-will-ferrell-tina-fey/)

Here is another [video interview](http://www.imdb.com/video/screenplay/vi3529611545/) where Will Ferrell explains that it's because he's an outsider and he does not have anyone to tell him how it should be pronounced.

Comment: Will used the same joke again in The Lego Movie, mispronouncing many of the mysterious artifacts, like the "Orb of Tee-tell-ist".

Answer (score 4):

Rather than an homage, it's a subtle statement of how isolated Megamind is. How friendless do you have to be to be unaware of how to pronounce "Hello"?

<strike>Of course, you have to forget that it's Will Ferrell acting and therefore *subtle* was probably not the intention.</strike>

**Edit:** The above slur on Will Ferrell is withdrawn in recognition of [the interview](https://www.imdb.com/videoplayer/vi3529611545) quoted in the other answer.